# Crashlytics doesn't report crashes on iOS 7

Tags: ios, report, dashboard, crashlytics

I have searched through all the posts concerning this issue but haven't found any solution. I have added Crashlytics framework to my App but I don't get any crash reports when I do `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]`. I have let the app crash on my development device as well as on the simulator with XCode disconnected. Has anybody had the same issue with this? My app is running on iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

The Crashlytics support helped me to get this fixed. If anybody has the same problem, send them a support request, they are very fast and stick to it until your problem is solved.